# How do I add class weights in R to logistic regression?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, weighted

As I understand, I have to add the parameter weights to the call where weights is a column in my data:
 `model <- glm(ATTESTED ~ DIFFERENCE * STRIDENT + C1 + C2, data = train, family = "binomial"(link = "logit"), REML=TRUE, weights=weights)`
How do I assign weights automatically? I want to assign different weights to my to classes.

Comment: What if I want to use different weights for different classes?

Comment: You would use `weights = train$weights`, or whatever the weights column in `train` is called. What do you mean assign weights automatically?

Comment: You may want to ask this at Cross Validated. But using weights with binary GLM can be fraught and often isn’t needed or appropriate. Generally the `weights` argument is for when your DV is an aggregate probability from multiple binary trials, which it doesn’t sound like is the case here? See [this relevant CV answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/386913/140918).

Comment: You need to decide how to create your weights column in the dataset. For example, `train$weights <- ifelse(train$hair == "blonde", 2, 1)` would give double weight to people with blonde hair. Then you can use `weights = train$weights` or just `weights = weights` in your glm call.